# How to configure a remote mysql connection?

Tags: mysql, database, connection, privileges, sql-grant

I am trying to configure a remote access to a mysql database. Whenenever I open MySQL Workbench and try to access to my remote server I get this:

> Failed to Connect to MySQL at xx.xxx.xx.xx:3306 with user root
>
> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xxx.xx.xx' (10060)

I've been searching the solution so my first step was to edit the my.cnf file and comment these lines:

```
#skip-external-locking 
#bind-address       = 127.0.0.0
```

And then I granted the privileges inside the MySQL server using:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

so if I use

```
SHOW GRANTS for root@'%';

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@%                                                                                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '******' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

But still didn't work. So I checked the netstat so I could see if there was an active connection over 3306 port.

```
~# netstat -an
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Is that even the correct output? I don't know. The thing is it does not work neither.
I also tryied to restart several times the mysql process without any success.

Thanks.

Comment: You should Change `bind-address       = 127.0.0.0` to your external ip address

Comment: I did dad too @Jens, but if I edit  and write `bind-address = my-public-ip` that's what I get when I restart the server for saving changes:

`~# service mysql restart
mysql stop/waiting
start: Job failed to start`